# Strip HTML from Django template block?

Tags: django, django-templates

In my Django `base.html` template I have a `title` block:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

In a page template I use the text from its `<h1>` page title in that block, so it also appears in the `<title>` tag, e.g.:

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>{% block title %}Hello world!{% endblock %}</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

That all works fine. But if I want to use HTML tags within the page's `<h1>` like this...

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    {% block title %}<b>Hello</b> world!{% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
```

...those tags will also appear in the `<title>`, which isn't allowed.

Is there a way around this other than having two versions of the title: one within `<h1>`, and one HTML-free version within a `{% block title %}`? I don't *think* there's a way to strip HTML from a block?

Comment: Only work-around I can think of is give the block within `h1` a different name.

Comment: Yeah, that - having two differently-named blocks - is what I was hoping to avoid. 90% of pages only need a single `title` block. But a handful have HTML in the `<h1>`.

Comment: You can use [`striptags`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#striptags) template filter if you're passing the value from your views.

Comment: @xyres I'm not passing the value from the views; this is text/html in the templates, as shown.

Comment: I'm interested to know why my question was downvoted...

Comment: I'm trying to tackle this issue but I see that Django's default behaviour doesn't allow the same block to be placed twice within the same file. Could you indicate how you overcame this?

Comment: @DavidAmores you're right, sorry! I've edited the question to remove the duplicate blocks, which didn't affect the fundamental problem I was trying to solve. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `cycle` like so:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
        <h1>
            {% block title %}
            {% cycle '' '<b>' %}Hello world!{% cycle '' '</b>' %}
            {% endblock %}
        </h1>
{% endblock %}
```

Hope this helps